# Select "this" element after dynamic created on button-click with jQuery

Tags: jquery, this, parent-child

I am trying to have a button-click event create a bunch of boxes on screen. I need each box (div) to create another div within it, and then be able to call on that div in particular for styling.

Right now, I have classes assigned to each, but how can I use `$(this)` to grab **only the newly-created (last) div by class**, rather than select every element on the page?

I'm running into problems particularly with *child* and *this* commands.

HTML:

```
<body>
  <button id="add-product">Add Product</button>
  <section class="products">
    <div class="outer">
      <div class="inner"></div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

JQUERY:

```
$('#add-product').on('click', function() {
  // Call addProduct() function
  addProduct();
});

// Add-Product Function
var addProduct = function() {
  $('.products').append("<div></div>").children().addClass('image');

  var lastdiv = $('.image').last();
  $(lastdiv).append("<div></div>");

  var innerdiv = $(lastdiv).children();  
  $(innerdiv).addClass('overlay');
};
```

Comment: it looks to me like you're adding empty divs, so they don't have children, which is probably where you're running into trouble.

Comment: ^^ what he said `$('<div></div>').children()` surely doesn't match anything, there are no children, so what are you trying to do here ?

Comment: @adeneo, @eriese `append()` returns the original context, in this case `$('.products')`, the `children()` is performed on `$('.products')` then.

Comment: now I don't understand what exactly the div you mean is.

Comment: I see no `this` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Just store the newly created element (in a variable) before appending it:

```
var addProduct = function() {
  var $newDiv = $("<div>");
  $('.products').append($newDiv).children().addClass('image');

  var $newInnerDiv = $("<div>");
  $newDiv.append($newInnerDiv);

  $newInnerDiv.addClass('overlay');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create proper elements that can be referenced

```
$('#add-product').on('click', function() {
    var div1 = $('<div />', {'class': 'image'}),
        div2 = $('<div />', {'class': 'overlay'});

    $('.products').append( div1.append( div2 ) );
});
```

All this appending and children nonsense is totally uneccessary to add a class to a newly created element